# Lie groupoids being homotopy equivalent

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, lie-groupoids

Let $M,N$be two smooth manifolds. Let $f,g:M\rightarrow N$ be two smooth maps. We have the notion of a homotopy (smooth homotopy) from the maps $f$ to the map $g$.

Is there a similar concept for morphisms of Lie groupoids?

Suppose $\mathcal{G}=(\mathcal{G}_1\rightrightarrows \mathcal{G}_0)$ and  $\mathcal{H}=(\mathcal{H}_1\rightrightarrows \mathcal{H}_0)$ be Lie groupoids.

Let $(\phi_1,\phi_0),(\psi_1,\psi_0): \mathcal{G}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ be two morphisms of Lie groupoids. Is there any notion of a “homotopy” from $(\phi_1,\phi_0)$ to $(\psi_1,\psi_0)$?

Further, is there a notion of when two Lie groupoids are homotopy equivalent?

Is there a notion for topological groupoids?

Comment: Thank you @YCor

Comment: There might be more than one: do you want to consider that equivalences of groupoids are homotopy equivalences, or you want to keep the information of the space of objects ?

Comment: @SimonHenry I want to keep information on the space of objects.. I do not know if it is reasonable to call equivalence of Lie groupoids as Homotopy equivalence

Comment: Another source to learn about when two Lie groupoids are homotopy equivalent is the homotopy theory created by Joost Nuiten: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10485-019-09563-z. If I had more time, I'd try to dig into the paper to find the weak equivalences, but I'm swamped. So I just leave you the reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is! Here is one way to go.

If $X=(X_{1}\rightrightarrows X_{0})$ is a topological groupoid, then $X\times [0,1]=(X_{1}\times[0,1]\rightrightarrows X_{0}\times[0,1])$ is also a topological groupoid.

So the notion of homotopy is:  if $f,f':X\rightarrow Y$ are two maps, then a homotopy between them is a map $F:X\times[0,1]\rightarrow Y$ that restricts to $f$ and $f'$ at $X\times\{0\}$ and $X\times\{1\}$.

And as soon as you have the notion of a homotopy of maps, you have the notion of a homotopy equivalence, defined as usual to be a pair of maps $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y\rightarrow X$ and a pair of homotopies between the composites $fg$ and $gf$ and the respective identity maps.

Comment: I think I am missing something here...You are only saying about Homotopy equivalence of topological spaces... There is a +1 to your answer, so, there must be something interesting in your answer, it is just that I am misunderstanding

Comment: it might be confusing because it's formally identical to "homotopy equivalence" of topological spaces. But in the above all the objects are topological groupoids and all maps between them are maps of groupoids. Note that a topological space gives rise to a pretty canonical topological groupoid by declaring that there are no non-identity morphisms, i.e. the space $X$ becomes the groupoid $X\rightrightarrows X$.

Comment: Yes, that one I am aware of associating a topological groupoid for a topological space, Lie groupoid for a manifold.. Has this formal notion of Homotopy equivalence used any where else in literature, in similar way a notion of homotopy equivalence of topological spaces used?

Comment: Yeah, this is the standard notion of homotopy for groupoids. In fact this construction using the "cylinder object" $X\times[0,1]$ is the standard way to define "homotopy" in any model category see pg 233-234 of Quillen's "Rational Homotopy theory"

Comment: I believe that is the standard way to talk about Homotopy equivalences. But, I was thinking if we should consider the category of Lie groupoids whose morphisms are morphisms of Lie groupoids or that of bibundles (I have the set up of differentiable stacks in mind).. So, in that case should we involve the notion of bibundle (generalized morphism) when defining the notion of Homotopy equivalence?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik you said in a comment on the question that you want to keep the space of objects. If you consider principal bibundles as morphisms instead of the morphisms in the answer, you only keep information about orbits of points and about their stabilisers.

Comment: @SebastianGoette So, can you please tell me what you feel could be another choice for the definition of Homotopy equivalence?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I am sorry, I am just learning groupoids myself. But here is my naive comment anyway: If you want to view a Lie groupoid with a single object as a Lie group $G$, then the version in the answer fits nicely. If you want to view the very same groupoid as a model for the classifying space $BG$ (as a differentiable stack), then you should use some version that is compatible with principal bibundles. It seems to me that both versions make sense, depending on the context.

Comment: @SebastianGoette Please let me know if you have any favorite reference for this set up?